# Android Location Updates simply not working when defined as global variables... Weird bug

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location, google-maps-android-api-2

Really weird bug - I can get location updates working like this:

```
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 1, new LocationListener() {

    //On location changed code here
    }
```

But not like this:

Global variables:

```
   LocationManager lManager;
   LocationListener lListener;
```

In my code:

```
   lManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

   lListener = new LocationListener() {

   //On location changed code goes here...
   }

   lManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 1, lListener);
```

Why are lListener/lManager global? One, they're used in the code elsewhere for other location polling. Two, I need them global so I can properly quit the locationservice on pause.

Anyone have any ideas? I'm stumped!

EDIT: One more thing: There are no errors, but the app right now just gets the location once, rather than polling every 2 seconds!

Comment: What error it is showing

Comment: No error, just I have some debug toasts which detect when location has changed, and parts of my app activate (with their own toasts) again, on location change. I don't see any of those. I should add that location is detected upon the app first opening, but there isn't any constant polling!

Comment: Is your gps enabled??

Comment: Yep, GPS is enabled and as I said above, I get location once but that's it! No constant polling.

Comment: It will not poll automatically , you have to do something to get the location update.

Comment: Using the first code, it polls automatically, though!